# Multilingual Not working For Date Picker Android

Tags: android, kotlin

We have some issue with Date picker when change the locale of Android App. any one can help me out.

When we change the language of Device Francia(Canada) then app is working fine with this code

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Locale.setDefault(resources.configuration.locales.get(0))
    }else{
        Locale.setDefault(resources.configuration.locale)
    }
```

but if we change the locale of app without change the device language from setting the getting incorrect result.

```
var locale=Locale(SharedPreferencesManager.getStringPreference(Constants.LOCALE, ""))
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val resources = resources
    val configuration = resources.configuration
    val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
        createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    } else {
        configuration.locale=locale
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics)
    }
```

[Correct View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVkOn.jpg)

[Incorrect View(Cancel and OK button not change as per app locale )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCvMo.jpg)

Comment: What is the "incorrect result", and what would be the expected result?

Comment: Language not change for complete Android Material DatePickerDialog.

Comment: Expected result: Complete Date picker should be change behalf of App Locale

Answer (score 0):

According to the http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25107 bug report on Android framework, the date picker is not using the String array of the shortened month of the Context of the app. Instead, it uses the System Locale.

You can use [AppLocaleDatePickerDialog.java](https://gist.github.com/gilbertwat/4631571) written by Gilbertwat.

Comment: That `AppLocaleDatePickerDialog.java` was created 8 years ago. Does the problem really persists till today?